#  recursive regular expression to process nested strings enclosed by {| and |}

Tags: php, regex, recursion

In a project I have a text with patterns like that:

{| text {| text |} text |}
more text

I want to get the first part with brackets. For this I use preg_match recursively. The following code works fine already:

```
preg_match('/\{((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*\}/x',$text,$matches);
```

But if I add the symbol "|", I got an empty result and I don't know why:

```
preg_match('/\{\|((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*\|\}/x',$text,$matches);
```

I can't use the first solution because in the text something like { text } can also exist. Can somebody tell me what I do wrong here? Thx

Comment: You can use Balancing groups in .NET like described here:
http://www.marcomilani.it/2012/07/english-nested-strings-with-regular-expressions-similar-to-recursive-regex.html?lang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
'/(?s)\{\|(?:(?:(?!\{\||\|\}).)++|(?R))*\|\}/'
```

In your original regex you use the character class `[^{}]` to match anything except a delimiter.  That's fine when the delimiters are only one character, but yours are two characters.  To not-match a multi-character sequence you need something this:

```
(?:(?!\{\||\|\}).)++
```

The dot matches any character (including newlines, thank to the `(?s)`), but only after the lookahead has determined that it's not part of a `{|` or `|}` sequence.  I also dropped your atomic group (`(?>...)`) and replaced it with a possessive quantifier (`++`) to reduce clutter.  But you should definitely use one or the other in that part of the regex to prevent [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: I just tried your solution and it works well. Thank you very much! And also thanks for the explanation, because it's not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few suggestions for working regular expressions, but if you're wondering why your original regexp failed, read on. The problem lies when it comes time to match a closing "|}" tag. The `(?>[^{}]+)` (or `[^{}]++`) sub expression will match the "|", causing the `|}` sub expression to fail. With no backtracking in the sub expression, there's no way to recover from the failed match.

Answer (score 0):

See [PHP - help with my REGEX-based recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896647/php-help-with-my-regex-based-recursive-function)

To adapt it to your use

```
preg_match_all('/\{\|(?:^(\{\||\|\})|(?R))*\|\}/', $text, $matches);
```