# PHP nested regex

Tags: php, regex

This string:

```
$subject = '\displaystyle{\ce{Cu^{2+}{(aq)}}+\ce{Zn{(s)}}\ce{->}\ce{Cu_{(s)}}+\ce{Zn^{2+}_{(aq)}}}'
```

I want to capture:

- \ce{Cu^{2+}{(aq)}}
- \ce{Zn{(s)}}
- \ce{->}
- \ce{Cu_{(s)}}
- \ce{Zn^{2+}_{(aq)}}

My regex inspired by [PHP - help with my REGEX-based recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896647/php-help-with-my-regex-based-recursive-function/1896711)

```
$pattern = '#\\\\ce\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*}#';
```

I tried with

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => \ce{->}
        )
 )
```

But it doesn't work as you can see...

Comment: do you want a new regex or just why its not working ? Whats your question ?

Comment: Yes, if you have a new regex... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your can use this recursive regex:

```
(\\ce(\{(?:[^{}]|(?-1))*\}))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/1)

Here `(?-1)` **recurses** the 2nd **subpattern** that starts after `\\ce`.

#### Code:

```
$re = "/(
  \\\\ce
  (
    \\{
    (?:[^{}]|(?-1))*
    \\}
  )
)/x"; 

$str = 
 "\displaystyle{\ce{Cu^{2+}{(aq)}}+\ce{Zn{(s)}}\ce{->}\ce{Cu_{(s)}}+\ce{Zn^{2+}_{(aq)}}}"; 

if ( preg_match_all($re, $str, $m) )
   print_r($m[1]);
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => \ce{Cu^{2+}{(aq)}}
    [1] => \ce{Zn{(s)}}
    [2] => \ce{->}
    [3] => \ce{Cu_{(s)}}
    [4] => \ce{Zn^{2+}_{(aq)}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my tests.
Note that `\ce` cannot be a sub-pattern without balanced braces.
So, this will fail `\ce{Zn\cepp{(s)}}`,
and, this will pass `\ce{Zn^{2+}\ce{Zn^{2+}_{(aq)}}_{(aq)}}`
otherwise, why look for `\ce{}` in the first place ?

```
 #  '/\\\ce(\{(?:(?>(?!\\\ce)[^{}])+|(?R)|(?1))*\})/'

 \\ce
 (                  # (1 start)
      \{
      (?:
           (?>
                (?! \\ce )         # Not '\ce' ahead
                [^{}]              # A char, but not { or }
           )+
        |                   # or,
           (?R)               # Recurse whole expression
        |                   # or,
           (?1)               # Recurse group 1
      )*
      \}                
 )                  # (1 end)
```

Comment: @benoitMariaux - You're welcome. Though, looks like you accepted an answer that can match `\ce` without braces. Well, good luck parsing.